# Why can't UI components be accessed from a backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, backgroundworker

Threads all share resources. That's the whole problem around multi-threaded operations.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) says:

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event >handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.
>
> BackgroundWorker events are not marshaled across AppDomain boundaries. Do not use a BackgroundWorker component to perform multithreaded operations in more than one AppDomain.

And yet when I use the backgroundworker, it's not that I need to be careful not to manipulate any UI objects, it's that can't_ if I try to access the UI components from the DOWork event. The code compiles, but when the code for the DoWork runs, I get an error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'utAlerts' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

MSDN doesn't say anything about how is this done or why. Is the backgroundworker decorated with some attribute that prevents this? How is this accomplished?

Comment: @Martinho: Sorry, it does compile, but I get the cross-thread not valid error. See my changes to my question. I am not sure why I thought it wouldn't compile. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're handler is an instance method in your UI class, you should have access to the members of that class.

> it's that my app won't even compile if I try to access the UI components from the DOWork event.

This will only happen if your `DoWork` handler is static or in a different class than the UI components.  In that case, you may not have access to them, as they are not visible to you.

---

Edit:

BackgroundWorker is intended to do "work" that is unrelated to your User Interface.  You cannot change User Interface elements on any thread other than the UI thread, as user interface elements tend to have thread affinity.  This actually has nothing to do with BackgroundWorker, but rather threading and user interface elements.

BW is intended to work around this by giving you progress and completion events that are automatically marshalled back onto the UI thread for you, allowing you to change UI elements there.  However, you can always do this directly yourself via `Control.Invoke` in Windows Forms or `Dispatcher.Invoke` in WPF.

As to how this works - It depends on what framework you're using.  For example, in Windows Forms, every `Control` (which is the base class of all of the UI elements) has a Handle, and the Handle is internally a native window handle.  This handle is used to [check the window's Thread ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) against the current thread ID.  This allows the check to be made without storing extra variables.

Comment: Sorry Reed, I made a mistake. For some reason I thought it wouldn't compile, but it does, I am just gettting the cross-thread error.

Comment: @Nick: I edited to include this.  @Richard: See my edit for more details on why this is occurring... It actually doesn't have anything to do with BackgroundWorker (directly)

Comment: BTW - Curious as to why the downvotes?  What I posted was exactly accurate, given the original post...

Comment: +1 for the info that it is the control preventing the cross-thread update, not BW directly.

Answer (score 4):

The error that you get when you try to change/update UI controls with a `BackgroundWorker` has nothing to do with sharing resources over the thread. It simply states that you cannot alter a control that was created on another thread.

```
  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {   
        textBox1.Text = "Test";
  }

Results in:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

This is used so that multiple threads are not accessing/changing the same controls at the same time. `BackgroundWorkers` are Asynchronous and could cause a lot of problems if controls were updated while the main thread updating them as well.

I do not know how they achieved this, however, it is probably in the best interest that they prevented this from happening.

The MSDN provided another line of documentation to the segment you copied which states "BackgroundWorker events are not marshaled across AppDomain boundaries. Do not use a BackgroundWorker component to perform multithreaded operations in more than one AppDomain."

EDIT CORRESPONDES TO CONVERSATION IN COMMENTS:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {   
        textBox1.Text = "Test";
    }
```

With the addition of the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false, this code executes without error.

In the summary of the boolean property, it states that it indicates whether to "catch calls on the wrong thread."

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, this is the error I get, and I want to know how it was achieved.

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: I just edited the question with the segment about "AppDomains." Because the BackgroundWorker_DoWork function is not in the same AppDomain as the Thread that your Form1 and all it's controls were created, you cannot access them.

Comment: @Richard: From the MSDN; "Multiple application domains can run in a single process; however, there is not a one-to-one correlation between application domains and threads. Several threads can belong to a single application domain, and while a given thread is not confined to a single application domain, at any given time, a thread executes in a single application domain."

Comment: @Richard: [Override the CrossThread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548866/what-can-i-access-from-a-backgroundworker-without-cross-threading) Apparently, it can also get overridden.

Comment: @Kyle: But it seems weird that a backgroundworker would operate in a different appdomain. Doesn't it? Can you find any proof of this?

Comment: @Richard: I think that the ability to AllowCrossThreading, and it working with a BackgroundWorker disproves my different AppDomain statement. It must make a check to see which Thread created an object and checks to see if you are on that thread, or another one.

Comment: @Richard: You're definitely not in a different AppDomain here - the issue is the cross thread checks.  That being said, disabling that check is **very bad**, and can lead to unstable behavior.  You should use Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to marshal the call back to the UI instead, since the requirement is really coming from the native Window handles.

Comment: @Reed: I think what Richard was really trying to understand here is how the system prevents you from accessing the UI controls. Martinho gave us a very good example of how to check which Thread an object was created on vs the Thread that is accessing it. I don't think he wants a way AROUND the check, just how the check is performed.

Comment: @Kyle: The check is actually not performed the way Martinho described - though that's a simple way to do this yourself, if that's required.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with something as simple as having each control store the current thread (or maybe just its ID) in a private field in the constructor and then checking if the current thread is still that one before every method. Something like this:

```
class ThreadAffineObject
{
    private readonly Thread originalThread;
    public ThreadAffineObject()
    {
        this.originalThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    }

    private void PreventCrossThreadOperation()
    {
        if(Thread.CurrentThread != originalThread)
            throw new CrossThreadOperationException();
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        PreventCrossThreadOperation();
        // Actually do stuff
    }

    private int someField;
    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get { return someField; } // here reading is allowed from other threads
        set
        {
            PreventCrossThreadOperation(); // but writing isn't
            someField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool. So do you think every control does this? Is this some interface or something that every control implements?

Comment: @Richard: there's no need to have an interface. As you can see from my sample implementation, there isn't anything public about the cross-thread prevention mechanism: both the check and the stored ID are private. I could check this by looking directly at the source, but I don't have Reflector anymore :(