# linq to sql query in a background worker Invalid cross-thread access

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone, backgroundworker

This code throws a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access exception`.

```
private void DoWorker(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    using (DbContext db = new DbContext(DbContext.littreConnectionString))
    {
        if (db.DatabaseExists())
        {
            var searchResults = from dbObject in db.LDicTable
                                where dbObject.word == SearchBox.Text
                                select dbObject;
            if (!searchResults.Any())
            {
                wordExists = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access text box in background worker dowork method as it executes in seperate thread not in UI thread

Comment: Store text box text in some string and use that variable in method

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, specify the framework that you use. Is it winforms? What "phone" tag is supposed to mean?

Comment: Also, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599164/why-cant-ui-components-be-accessed-from-a-backgroundworker

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that it for windows phone 8, dbContext is a class derived from datacontext i already know that i cant access the ui tread from the doWork method but only from the events (progress, complete) but the exception is raised when am trying to check if the query returned any value,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because You cannot access UI thread objects in background worker dowork method as it executes in seperate thread not in UI thread.so it is executing in different thread and you try to access UI thread object.

You have to Store text box text in some string and use that variable in method.

See following link for details :

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/623667/BackGroundWorker-Thread-issue-with-UI-Thread

[Why can't UI components be accessed from a backgroundworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599164/why-cant-ui-components-be-accessed-from-a-backgroundworker)