# Are there any restrictions or special requirements when calling a method in a backgroundWorker DoWork section?

Tags: backgroundworker

This question is related to direction provided to me in another post (see [How can I stop a method using a Cancel button in visual C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195663/how-can-i-stop-a-method-using-a-cancel-button-in-visual-c)). My question, is whether there are any restrictions when creating a BackgroundWorker, as far as called methods are concerned? I have a method that executes fine outside the DoWork section of my BackgroundWorker, but the moment it is placed inside the DoWork, I get a Cross Thread error stating "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control "txtFileOutput" accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." I know the BackgroundWorker is working with a basic for loop and have validated that. The "txtFileOutput" control referenced in the error is a textbox, to which I'm piping output from a regex query against a file (this is the method I'm trying to call within the DoWork).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't UI components be accessed from a backgroundworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599164/why-cant-ui-components-be-accessed-from-a-backgroundworker)

Comment: @HenkHolterman This statement "TextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;", taken from the other post,  gets around the cross thread error, as does using "Invoke", however, the whole point of using the Background worker was to enable canceling of the method via a cancel button. If I use "TextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;", I can click on the Cancel button, but it does nothing to cancel the action now. I'm assuming the threads aren't lining up?

Comment: No, it does not "get around the error", it sabotages the smoke alarm. And Cancelling never was the problem, that is designed to be thread-safe.

Comment: @HenkHolterman So am I using the wrong approach here? I was originally trying to use async and await, then someone mentioned backgroundWorkers, so I tried this method, but now I'm running into issues updating the UI. Is there a better approach to executing a method that writes to the UI (textbox), with an option to cancel the method after it's been executed?

Comment: You could go async if you replace that ReadAllLines with something that is properly async. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50202452/60761) and follow the link in there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Have not had any luck with async tasks. This is becoming so complicated. Is it possible to just set a timer on the task where it automatically exits the method if it has ran longer than x Time?