# async/await does not work properly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have problem with async/await method of mine. I am new into async/await and seems I can't get it to work correctly.

The GUI freezes when I have the following.

```
private async void SetUpTextBox(string s)
{
    //This method is called in button event
    string textToSet = await GetTextA(s);
    read_Box.Text = textToSet;
}

private Task<string> GetTextA(string s)
{
    return Task.Run(() => GetText(s));
}

private string GetText(string s)
{
    string textToReturn = "Hello";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(s)))
    {
        textToReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return textToReturn;
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I know I am new into this and that's why I am here to learn (a.k.a don't judge!).

P.S When I tried to change

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(s)))
{
    textToReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

With simple `Thread.Sleep(2500)` method. The GUI doesn't freeze at all!

Comment: Note that your `GetText` function already exists, it's called `File.ReadAllText`.

Comment: I have tried that as well before I haven' mentioned that. It was still freezing the GUI tho.

Comment: You mention a GUI but don't tell us which one, and don't include how you connect to it. Write a proper [mcve] that includes the ButtonClick etc.

Comment: I have an hypothesis of why you are blocking the UI: the ammount of text you are trying to put in the line `read_Box.Text = textToSet;` (which runs in the UI thread) is too much. Edit: Of course, when the text is small, such as "Hello" it doesn't block the UI.

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry about that. Just normal winforms.

Comment: @HenkHolterman accidently ive put "exceptions occured" on your comment sorry.

Comment: @Theraot Yeah I have been using huge .txt files. I think that might be the problem too. I forgot to mention that too. I havent even tought of that it might be too much text... I will try to solve it with TPL once I will be abble to (Thunderstorm at the moment)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the things you should do, that you aren't:

- Using `ReadToEndAsync`.
- Avoiding `Task.Run` when the task is not CPU bound.
- Avoiding `async void` when the method is not an event handler.
- Having proper error handling.

Nkosi has done a decent job illustrating that.

What is left is explaining why `Thread.Sleep(2500)` does not block the UI.

---

First off, notice that `Task.Run` will be running the task using the `ThreadPool`.

You can verify that `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` is true inside of `GetText` (for example, you can set a break point and use inspections to check).

That means that the UI thread cannot be blocked inside of `GetText`, because the UI thread does not run `GetText`.

---

But why then `Thread.Sleep(2500);` yields a different result?

Hmmm... what is the difference between:

```
private string GetText(string s)
{
    string textToReturn = "Hello";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(s)))
    {
        textToReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return textToReturn;
}
```

And:

```
private string GetText(string s)
{
    string textToReturn = "Hello";
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
    return textToReturn;
}
```

Let me tell you:

- The possible exceptions thrown. Since you are not handling them - and I assume you are using a debug build in a debugger - you would have noticed. So, I do not think this is the problem. Even if you weren't, the exceptions are not from the UI thread, would go unhandled, and crash the application (Edit: I tested).
- The ammount of time it takes to execute. However, since the UI will not be blocked by this code - being it running in the `ThreadPool` - that is not it either.
- The ammount of text returned.

> When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth

-- Sherlock Holmes

The UI is being stuck because you are returning too much text.

---

Let me put this way...

**TOO MUCH TEXT RETURNED**

```
private string GetText(string s)
{
    string textToReturn = "Hello";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(s)))
    {
        textToReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return textToReturn;
}
```

*A little text returned:*

```
private string GetText(string s)
{
    string textToReturn = "Hello";
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
    return textToReturn;
}
```

---

The UI, is therefore being stuck at `read_Box.Text = textToSet;`, busy trying to render all the text that you got from the file. *Or at least that is my hyphothesis.*

Comment: Yeah "The UI, is therefore being stuck at read_Box.Text = textToSet;, busy trying to render all the text that you got from the file. Or at least that is my hyphothesis.". That was the problem. I split the text and then added each line slowly in async fashion to confirm that. Also thanks for the good practices you all have showed me!.. Really helped me out, and I have learned something new! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Avoid `async void` except for async event handlers, plus you can use `ReadToEndAsync` and make code async all the way through.

```
private async Task SetUpTextBox(string s) {
    //This method is called in button event
    string textToSet = await GetTextAsync(s);
    read_Box.Text = textToSet;
}

private async Task<string> GetTextAsync(string s) {
    string textToReturn = "Hello";
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(s))) {
        textToReturn = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    return textToReturn;
}
```

An example of calling `SetUpTextBox` within the button click event handler, as implied by the comment from original post

```
public async void OnBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    try {
        //...

        await SetUpTextBox("some path");

        //..
    } catch {
        //... handle error
    }
}
```

You should also put a `try/catch` around everything with the an async void event handler, otherwise any exceptions will go unobserved.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this and GUI still freezes up. Also I originaly wanted to try to "taskify" the synchronous method I created. As said it the GUI doesn't freeze when I change it with Thread.Sleep(n); method (That is why there is string textToReturn = "Hello"; just to return something after changing it to test it) . But it does freeze if I use stream reader.. And I need to use stream reader. Also I have changed to async task from async void.

Comment: There’s probably an exception getting thrown, try wrapping your streamreader code in a try-catch, being sure to catch AggregateException or just everything, then print to console.

Comment: I have tried that and i dont get anything. P.S I have changed it to console project so it opens console along side Form.

Answer (score -3):

Create an async void (for exemple Wait) with Thread.Sleep(x) inside and call it with "await Wait(x) ;" inside an async void.

Comment: Don't use Thread.Sleep in async code, use `Task.Delay(..)` (which you can `await`)

Comment: It is not a good idea to advice to create an async **void** method and a **blocking** call to `Thread.Sleep()` when there is something like `Task.Delay()`